# How to implement auction using CW721 Nft?

Tags: smartcontracts, cosmwasm

I am working on the auction smart contract. `cw721` token owners send nft to the auction contract and once the auction contract receives the `ReceiveNft(cw721::Cw721ReceiveMsg)` msg, the auction is started. The problem here is the data provided by `Cw721ReceiveMsg`. Its msg should be decoded to the custom data containing necessary information like start time, duration, minimum bid. My cw721 nft contract use the default msg handlers and I am lost how to customize this so that token owners can customize the data for the auction when the token is sent.

I tried to customize the `SendNft` handler to add submsgs to the response. But I can not just use dummy values for auctions as they should be set by the token owners. Not sure about the project architecture as well. Current cw721 nft only contrains lib file which simply implemented the `cw721` with metadata.